# Copying specific data from one sheet to another using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks:
Source.xlsm, sheet= Orig and
Destination.xlsm, sheet=New

I am trying to move data between these sheets in a specific way: Example of both sheets before running the macro (the column ordering is on purpose)

[image]
[image]

My objective is to take only the rows from Orig with today's date and place all of them in a specific ordering to the end of the New sheet. So that after running the macro, New looks like:

[image]

Any suggestions as to how to progress would be amazing

I have the following code snippets to start to form a solution, all saved in Source.xlsm. This works apart from the added complication of empty columns in both sheets that would be filled out manually with other data that isn't moved/ edited with during the macro execution. Wihtou the empty columns on each sheet, this works.

```
Sub TransferToday()
    
    Const CriteriaColumn As Variant = 4
    ' The leading "0, "-s are used to be able to use sCols(c)
    ' instead of sCols(c - 1) in the For...Next loop.
    Dim sCols() As Variant: sCols = VBA.Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
    Dim dCols() As Variant: dCols = VBA.Array(0, 2, 4, 3, 1)
    
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(sCols)
    Dim Today As Date: Today = Date ' TODAY() in excel
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks("Destination.xlsm")
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets("New")
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, cCount)
    
    ' Prevent copying if an occurrence of today's date is found in destination.
    ' If not needed, out-comment or delete, it doesn't interfere with the rest.
 '   Dim dCol As Variant
 '   dCol = dCols(Application.Match(CriteriaColumn, sCols, 0) - 1)
'    If IsNumeric(Application.Match(CLng(Today), drg.Columns(dCol), 0)) Then
'        MsgBox "Today's data had already been transferred.", vbExclamation
'        Exit Sub
'    End If
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets("Orig")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, cCount)
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = srg.Value
    
    Dim dData() As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To srCount, 1 To cCount)
    
    Dim sr As Long
    Dim dr As Long
    Dim c As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        If IsDate(sData(sr, CriteriaColumn)) Then ' is a date
            If sData(sr, CriteriaColumn) = Today Then ' is today's date
                dr = dr + 1
                For c = 1 To cCount
                    dData(dr, dCols(c)) = sData(sr, sCols(c))
                Next c
            End If
        End If
    Next sr
    
    If dr = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No today's data found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' First Destination Row.
    Dim dfrrg As Range: Set dfrrg = drg.Resize(1).Offset(drg.Rows.Count)
    
    dfrrg.Resize(dr).Value = dData
   
    MsgBox "Today's data transferred.", vbInformation
   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Copy to Different Columns

```vb
Sub TransferToday()
    
    Const ColumnTitlesList As String = "Name,Product,Quantity,Date"
    Const CriteriaColumnTitle As String = "Date" ' need not be in the titles
    
    Dim Today As Date: Today = Date ' TODAY() in excel
    
    Dim ColumnTitles() As String: ColumnTitles = Split(ColumnTitlesList, ",")
    Dim cUpper As Long: cUpper = UBound(ColumnTitles)
    
    Dim c As Long ' Column Indexes Counter
    
    ' Write the source data to an array.
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets("Orig")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion ' table
    Dim shrg As Range: Set shrg = srg.Rows(1) ' header row
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = srg.Value
    
    ' Determine the source column indexes.
    
    ' Criteria Column
    Dim sccIndex As Long
    sccIndex = Application.Match(CriteriaColumnTitle, shrg, 0)
    
    ' Copy Columns
    Dim scIndexes() As Long: ReDim scIndexes(0 To cUpper)
    For c = 0 To cUpper
        scIndexes(c) = Application.Match(ColumnTitles(c), shrg, 0)
    Next c
    
    ' Write today's source row data to arrays in a collection.
    
    ' This collection will hold...
    Dim sColl As Collection: Set sColl = New Collection
    ' ... as many of these arrays...
    Dim sArr As Variant: ReDim sArr(0 To cUpper)
    ' ... as there are records with today's date found.
    ' Note that no parentheses ('sArr()') are used to make it more readable
    ' (understandable) when the same variable is used as the control variable
    ' in the For Each...Next loop later in the code.
    
    Dim sr As Long ' Source Rows Counter

    For sr = 2 To srCount ' skip header row
        If IsDate(sData(sr, sccIndex)) Then
            If sData(sr, sccIndex) = Today Then
                For c = 0 To cUpper
                    sArr(c) = sData(sr, scIndexes(c))
                Next c
                sColl.Add sArr
            End If
        End If
    Next sr
    
    Erase sData ' data is in the collection ('sColl')
    
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = sColl.Count
    If drCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No today's data found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Write today's source data from the collection to arrays of an array.
    
     ' This AKA jagged array will hold...
    Dim dJag() As Variant: ReDim dJag(0 To cUpper)
    ' ... as many of these arrays...
    Dim dArr() As Variant: ReDim dArr(1 To drCount, 1 To 1)
    ' ... as there are columns to be copied.
    
    For c = 0 To cUpper
        dJag(c) = dArr
    Next c
     
    Dim dr As Long ' Destination Rows Counter
    
    For Each sArr In sColl
        dr = dr + 1
        For c = 0 To cUpper
            dJag(c)(dr, 1) = sArr(c)
        Next c
    Next sArr
    
    Set sColl = Nothing ' data is in the array of arrays ('dJag')
    
    ' Reference the destination range.
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' Workbooks("Destination.xlsm")
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets("New")
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion ' table
    Dim dhrg As Range: Set dhrg = drg.Rows(1) ' header row
    ' This is the range the new data will be written to.
    Set drg = drg.Resize(drCount).Offset(drg.Rows.Count)
    
    ' Determine the destination column indexes.
    
    ' Paste Columns
    Dim dcIndexes() As Long: ReDim dcIndexes(0 To cUpper)
    For c = 0 To cUpper
        dcIndexes(c) = Application.Match(ColumnTitles(c), dhrg, 0)
    Next c
    
    ' Write the data from the arrays of the array to the destination columns.
    
    For c = 0 To cUpper
        drg.Columns(dcIndexes(c)).Value = dJag(c)
    Next c
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Today's data transferred.", vbInformation
   
End Sub
```